# google glass notification mismatch development and production server

Tags: google-glass, google-mirror-api

I try to send notification through menu in my app using mirror api. for development environment I am using a proxy server but in production I am using just SSl cause it is public domain. my callback URL for this two section is bellow

// development
             callbackUrl = "https://3a4660af.ngrok.com/notify";

```
        // production
        if (callbackUrl.equals("https://www.mydomain.com:8080/notify")) {
           callbackUrl = "https://www.mydomain.com:8443/notify";
        } else {
           callbackUrl = "https://www.mydomain.com:8443/notify";
        }

        LOG.info("\ncallbackUrl : " + callbackUrl);

        Subscription subscription = new Subscription();
        subscription.setCollection(collection);
        subscription.setVerifyToken(userId);
        subscription.setCallbackUrl(callbackUrl);
        subscription.setUserToken(userId);


getMirror(credential).subscriptions().insert(subscription)
                .execute();
```

But when I try to read notification from notification class I got mismatch so that the notification action is not working. the notification log in bellow

```
    //development 
    got raw notification : { "collection": "timeline", 
"itemId": "6fa2445e-b14f-46b2-9cff-f0d44d63ecab", 
"operation": "UPDATE", "verifyToken": "103560737611562800385", 
"userToken": "103560737611562800385", 
"userActions": [  {   "type": "CUSTOM",   "payload": "dealMenu"  } ]}

    //production
    got raw notification :  "collection": "timeline", 
"operation": "UPDATE", 
"userToken": "103560737611562800385",  {   "payload": "dealMenu" ]null
```

in Notification class

```
BufferedReader notificationReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream()));
        String notificationString = "";

        // Count the lines as a very basic way to prevent Denial of Service
        // attacks
        int lines = 0;
        while (notificationReader.ready()) {
            notificationString += notificationReader.readLine();
            lines++;
            LOG.info("\ngot raw notification during read : "
                    + notificationString);
            // No notification would ever be this long. Something is very wrong.
            if (lines > 1000) {
                throw new IOException(
                        "Attempted to parse notification payload that was unexpectedly long.");
            }
        }

        LOG.info("\ngot raw notification : " + notificationString);

        JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

        LOG.info("\ngot jsonFactory : " + jsonFactory);
        // If logging the payload is not as important, use
        // jacksonFactory.fromInputStream instead.
        Notification notification = jsonFactory.fromString(notificationString,
                Notification.class);

        LOG.info("\n got notification " + notification);
```

In production I cannot received all the perimeters what I need. Why this mismatch happen???

Comment: The JSON you're posting for the production side looks malformed. Is that what you're actually getting?

Comment: then what can I do now. because I am using same code. If i use direct source in production tomcat server, then is there any possibility to give correct formate?

Comment: First of all, confirm here that this is the actual JSON you're getting on the production side and this isn't a cut/paste error. If it is, there are some possibilities, but I want to make sure this is it first.

Comment: OK, sound good. I add my subscriptions execute code.

Comment: How are you capturing and displaying the JSON returned?

Comment: On what? You're not showing the code for the callback function. The reason I'm asking is to try and determine if the JSON is being mangled inside your code, possibly inside a library, or in the web server before it is handed off to your app server.

Comment: Now please check it this understandable or not. I just read from Buffer and then add in a string  then make the string to JSON formate